# Image stretching in flexbox in Safari

Tags: css, image, safari, flexbox, height

This is only an issue in Safari and looks like a Safari bug to me. Here is a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0scrgd9j/) with a simplified version of the issue.

When an image is in a nested flexbox element with a width set and `height: auto` it is being stretched... the auto height is not working. Does something extra need to be added for this to work in Safari?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container section:first-child {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.container img {
  width: 125px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </section>
</div>
```

I expect the height of the image to automatically be adjusted to maintain aspect ratio. This works in all browsers except Safari. In Safari the image is stretched and the auto height does not work.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

It certainly appears to be a bug.

The default setting for [the **`align-items`** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) is `stretch`. Most major browsers handle this sensibly, stretching the image *within the confines of the container*.

For whatever reason, Safari stretches the image to its natural height, taking the container along for the ride.

---

### `flex-direction: row`

To fix the problem, override the `stretch` default value with `flex-start` in the `align-items` property.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container section:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; /* new */
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.container img {
  width: 125px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png">
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png">
  </section>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jtx01q3v/2/)

---

### `flex-direction: column`

Switching the direction of the flex container to `column` also fixes the problem. This works because `align-items` now applies to width *and* you've defined a width on the image.

If you reverse the image dimensions from

```
.container img {
   width: 125px;
   height: auto;
}
```

to

```
.container img {
   width: auto;
   height: 125px;
}
```

... you'll have the same problem in Safari as in `flex-direction: row`, and need `align-items: flex-start` for the correction.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container section:first-child {
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: flex-start; */
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.container img {
  width: auto;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png">
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png">
  </section>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vrtcbfdp/1)

Comment: Thanks for verifying and providing an explanation! Seems like Safari is quickly becoming the new IE.

Comment: Does Safari track this issue? If yes, it would be great to add a link.

Comment: Thank you for this! Does applying `align-items: flex-start;` permanently without caring about the `flex-direction` cause any problem if the `flex-direction` changes?

Comment: Sounds like the fix in WebKit has been merged in late 2020: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209983

Comment: @WildCat unfortunately this bug still persists as of 2021-05-21. Using `align-self: flex-start` is a nice way of getting around it.

Comment: Thank you `align-items: flex-start;` worked for me :)

Answer (score 15):

Adding height: intrinsic; works for me to fix the stretched height in safari. Add it to the image itself.  Not the wrapper.  You will still need height: auto for the other browsers.

Comment: This helped me too, and it seems to be the least intrusive option.

Comment: Same here, this one's the ticket!

Comment: Whoa, this is a very weird behavior. Good luck finding that on your own  Thanks @Kerry Murphy

Answer (score 6):

For me neither of the solutions worked. I already had both `flex-direction: column` and `align-items: center`, although, in my case, I also had some other elements in the same flex container, alongside the image. Not sure if it had any impact.

What actually fixed the issue in my case was simply wrapping the image with a div:

```
<section>
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: As well as setting the img's width to 100%.

Comment: This solution fixed the problem for me either.

Answer (score 5):

See my demo for a working example, add `flex-direction: column;` to fix this issue.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container section:first-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.container img {
  width: 125px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed adding `flex-direction: column;` fixes the issue as well but to me this shouldn't be needed. Could you explain why this needed? Or is this just a workaround for a Safari bug?

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 you could add class="flex-column flex-md-row" to restore it to horizontal on devices larger than a phone, but still get the fix in for iphones..

Answer (score 1):

if parent `<img/>` tag has `display:flex;` add `align-items: center;`

```
<div style="display:flex;align-items: center;">
    <img "img.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking over this post in the future: I had this problem with a fixed height `flex-direction:row` flexbox and images inside of flex-children with `height:100%`. The highest-voted solution wasn't enough to fix it.

For whatever reason, what ultimately fixed it in my case was adding `display:block` directly to the images.