# Image stretching out only on iPhone x

Tags: html, css, layout, iphone-x

I am currently designing and building a website in html and css, and have ran into a small issue. I checked responsiveness using the chrome dev tools (sizing the window to phone and tablet sizes), and everything looked fine. However now that I checked the site on my iPhone X, the images are all stretched out vertically. I have tried multiple things but none worked.

This is the way it looks in the chrome dev tools, with the iPhone X option selected, and with the screen set to the actual safari frame size (375, 632):

[image: Screenshot from chrome dev tools with the iPhone X option selected]

[image: Screenshot from chrome dev tools with the actual iPhone X safari frame size (375, 632)]

And here is a screenshot of what it actually looks like on my phone:
[image: Website on my physical phone]

This is the html layout of the frame:

```
<h1>Your 10 most watched series</h1>
<section class="series-image-list">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
</section>
```

And this is the corresponding css:

```
.series-image-list {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.series-image-list img {
    width: 35vh;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Any help as to why the images are stretched out vertically would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this maybe your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516373/image-stretching-in-flexbox-in-safari

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think this would be an issue with flexbox, thanks for helping!

Comment: Well, technically it's an issue with Safari :D