# Why is my picture stretched on mobile iphone safari?

Tags: html, css

In the second picture there is android, everything works fine.
But on iPhones 7 on safari the image is being stretched vertically. Why is this happening?
My html code and css

```
 <div class="configuration__grid">
                <div class="configuration__grid--box"> <img src="/img/bag.png" class="conf-img"
                        alt="picture">
                </div>
```

```
 .configuration__grid {
  display: flex;
}

.configuration__grid--box {
  flex: 0.5;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.conf-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: duplicate question, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516373/image-stretching-in-flexbox-in-safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using and see if it helps

object-fit: cover;

Check this link for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: how about adding also display:block to the img element?

Answer (score 0):

For the iPhone or MAC os, You always need to put an image inside a container,

Like:

```html
<div class="img-box">
 <img src="assert/img/pic.png"> 
</div>
```

For CSS you need to use this simple code:

```css
.img-box{
  width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
}
```

by using these above codes your iPhone and MAC image or picture stretch issue will be resolved

Thanks
Nantu Dutta